# Read the response body in an Android Spring Interceptor

Tags: java, android, spring, inputstream, interceptor

I'm using a simple Spring Interceptor class to log all REST requests/responses for the RestTemplate object in my Android app. So far everything works fine.

```
public class LoggerInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {

@Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
  ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {

Log.d(TAG, "Request body: " + new String(body));
// ...more log statements...

ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);

Log.d(TAG, "Response Headers: " + response.getHeaders());

return response;
}
```

At initialization I call:

```
List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
LoggerInterceptor loggerInterceptor = new LoggerInterceptor();
interceptors.add(loggerInterceptor);
restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
```

However I cannot log `response.getBody()` in the method above because the InputStream gets consumed once and throws an IllegalStateException when it is consumed again later. Is there a way around this so that I can log the response body too?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To allow for multiple `response.getBody()` calls wrap your ClientHttpRequestFactory in a BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory.

```
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = 
    new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory());
restTemplate.setRequestFactory(requestFactory);
```

Comment: Using the 3.1 Spring framework or later, this is definitely a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

Implement `ClientHttpResponse` yourself and add a `setBody(byte[] body)` method and override `getBody`. In your code above, you can then store the byte array in an `ByteArrayInputStream`, log what you want, then set the byte array back in the instance of your class that implements `ClientHttpResponse`, and that you can then return.